# Make Ubuntu suspend continue charging my ipod

Tags: ubuntu, usb, ipod, suspend

I would like ubuntu to continue charging my nano ipod thru usb even when it is suspended. This is because sometimes I switch on the laptop just to charge my ipod. I don't want to waste unnecessary power from my laptop and at the same time would like to charge my ipod.

Any script to do this in ubuntu or any other linux distro?

Answer (score 4):

This is not an operating system feature, but mostly your USB controller: to make it work a part of the controller that controls power of USB port must work even when laptop is mostly powered down, and also it's voltage converter (Li-Ion battery provides approx. 7-14 V, and chipset requires at least 3.3V and 5V) must provide a reasonable current to charge something (1A is max for one port by USB specification) while scattering heat (remember, fan doesn't work).

So this is a feature that requires much more hardware support than software, and therefore it is present in a few devices. For example, my Toshiba NB200 (Intel ICH7 chipset) has one USB port out of 3 that's powered while it is suspended, and that feature is enabled in BIOS: I found no settings in XUbuntu that may affect it, through there was some Windows XP utility IIRC.

To check if your laptop has this feature you can:

1. (Most easy) Check it's case and try to find a small 'lightning' mark near USB ports. There is one on mine, but I don't know if this is a de-facto standard.
2. (The obvoius) As this feature is relatively rare vendor probably wrote info about it several times: on the original box, in user manual or on some stickers on laptop itself.
3. As this is mostly chipset feature, you can determine yours and check chipset vendor's documentation on website.